# Triggering a POST request from inside a docker container running on GCP AI Platform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, http-post, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have deployed my model training inside a docker container which is executed as a job on the GCP AI platform. The python script performing the training occasionally triggers a post request to a django app running on my local machine. The post request fails with a HTTPConnectionError.

So, my question is :
how do I trigger a POST request from inside a container running on GCP AI platform?

Comment: How do you call your local machine? can you share this piece of code?

Comment: When you say local machine, I'm assuming you are accounting that your local machine needs a public IP address and the AI Platform training can reach the internet, please clarify connectivity and network settings.

Comment: @gogasca yes my local machine has a public IP and is connected to the internet. As far as the AI platform's connectivity goes, I'm assuming it can be slow due to region, but it is definitely connected to the internet.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the relevant code for the POST request : 

`
    import requests
    post_url='http://'+ip_port+'/job-logs/{}'.format(job_id)
    requests.post(post_url, data = {'status' : 1})
`

Answer (score 1):

Your machine is connected to internet, I have no doubt about this.

However, is it directly connected to the internet? Or are you behind a box and connected to local network?

On windows, you can check this with `ipconfig`, on linux with `/sbin/ifconfig`. If you have a private IP (most of the time 192.168.x.x), you need to configure your box router to route the inbound connexion to your internal IP (on which your local machine is listening).

In addition, the IP attribution is, most of the time, performed with DHCP (automatic distribution). You also need to configure your box router to reserve a local private IP in your network to your local machine. Else, at the next reboot, you could have a different IP and the previous routing setup will have to be done again.